# Reactivity of carbonyl adjacent to cyclopropyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image: Blockquote]

We know that cyclopropyl, because of $\ce{sp^{\sim 5}}$,  hybrid orbitals behaves much like a double bond. It even takes part in conjugation to stabilise positive charge on carbons adjacent to it. I would like to know if it conjugates with the carbonyl carbon too?

Are there cases of 1,4 addition and 1,2 addition with such compounds analogous to that observed in alpha-beta unsaturated carbonyl compounds?